# How to fix 'Test framework quit unexpectedly' using espresso and junit? - Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-studio-3.5

I am new in espresso test and i would like to test my project with espresso, but it show error 'Test framework quit unexpectedly'

I've tried:

- uninstall app in my phone and it's still show error like before
- clean project and rebuild project in android studio and it's still show error like before
- invalidates cache/restart android studio and it's still show error like before

And this is the error:

> Testing started at 06:15 ...
>
> 09/26 06:15:56: Launching 'MainActivityEspresso...' on Lenovo Lenovo A6010.
>
> Installation did not succeed.
>
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK
>
> Installation failed due to: 'null'
>
> Retry

this is the screenshot: 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWVQF.jpg 'espresso result error and gradle'

Comment: Please share your build.gradle !

Comment: it was included in that screenshot